# Network drives showed multiple time in file browser

Tags: networking, nautilus, 17.04

My local network drives are displayed several time in nautilus due to different network protocols. 
One is SMB and, I guess, the other one is AFP. I stopped the AFP service on the network drives (rather old WD) but they are still around and I have an authorization error when clicking. 
Is there a way to have it only once?

[image: Network drive list in Ubuntu]

Comment: If you click on the stopped service then obviously you get an error.
Likely the information is cached, so as per your example disable the AFP service and reboot.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You mean AFP on the network drive or on my ubuntu desktop? If it is on the ubuntu Desktop, I have no idea how to do that! Any hint? If it is on the Network Drive, it is done on the one offering the option. But the network drive still shows...

Comment: You wrote in your question "I stopped the AFP service ". I am saying that by stopping the service, the information about the drives does not auto-refresh in the cache memory of your Ubuntu. Reboot Ubuntu is one sure way to clear the cache.

Comment: I rebooted a few times and still I had both the AFP drive and Windows share appearing. Not so much a trouble than a bother. Especially as my drive is down and maybe defintively...

Comment: I'm out of ideas...